# when should I make a function that has parameters / arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameters

when should we actually create a function that has parameters / arguments?

today I made a programming project. Then it occurred to me when should I actually create a function that has parameters .. I usually create it when there is a global value / variable and that value must exist in some function then I make that value the argument of the function .. did I do it right? or wrong? if wrong what are the best practices for doing it?

```
varGlobal = "test"
def foo():
    print(varGlobal)

# or

def foo(parm):
    print(parm) # parm -> varGlobal


def foo():
    ask = input("ask")
    print(ask)

# or

def foo(parm):
    print(parm) # parm -> global user input
```

Comment: Honestly all of these option are ok.

Comment: I have been coding Python professionally for many years, and I have the opposite issue: I hardly ever need global variables, but I need function parameters all the time =)

Comment: There are two significantly different questions here. The global is almost never the correct choice (but there are corner cases where it can be a better choice). Whether to call `input` in your function or have the caller provide the input depends very much on how `foo` is intended to be used. As a general rule, try to push input "up" or towards the edge of your program as much as a possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's *usually* a good idea to use parameters. Consider what the purpose of the function is. Parameterized functions are more generally useful than non-parameterized functions.

If the first case, is whatever `foo` does applicable only to a single value, or could it be useful for *arbitrary* values, regardless of what variable might refer to them? In the former case, you are stuck using `varGlobal`. In the latter, the call can always use `foo(varGlobal)` if that's the necessary argument.

In the second, might `foo` be useful to someone who already has a value, and doens't need to call `input`? In the former case, you are stuck calling `input`. In the latter, the caller can always use `foo(input())` or the like if they really need to call `input`.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest that you should use parameters and arguments in every function. it simply makes the whole process of design simpler.
You can clear see what data the function uses, and what it returns.

The only use of global values (either module globals, or globals imported from other modules are :

- Module or application wide constants
- Module or application wide function or classes (which are in Python efectively module level 'globals'.

Your functions should always return values and never change a global value (by definition if you stick to the above list that you wont be changing anything).

In my opinon using the 'global' keyword is never needed (in 8 years of coding I have never needed it, or identified a reason to use it).

Answer (score 0):

Using global **variables** is bad practice in any language [GlobalVariablesAreBad](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad)

Comment: Using *mutable* global values is usually a bad idea. Global variables are the very reason Python functions can even call other functions that aren't defined locally. `def foo(x): return bar(x) + 5`? `bar` is a global variable.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this explanation may solve the question, including a sample code  would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. I suggest you to edit your answer to add some code example, Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Global variables can be used if you need to access or modify the variable in several methods/classes in the same module.
Remember you need to point `global my_global_variable` to modify the variable.

Parameters are variables needed in the method to do the processing. These variables should live locally in the method. If you need to retrieve something from the method, you should add a `return` statement. Also, if you need to return several variables you can return as tuple.

So, in this way, you're organizing your code, making all variables visible to other people. Also I recommend you to use docstrings to fully document your methods, variables and processing.

Comment: If the value is important - pass it as a paramter. changing a global value is a recipe for spaghetti code which is complex to trace.

Answer (score 0):

When we need to solve the same sort of question but with different arguments.  So you don't have to write the same function over and over again. Let's say you want to write a function that will return the square of the provided number as an argument.
So you write

```
def square(num):
    return num*num
```

So every time you need to have square of a number..you just put that number in place of the argument and not write the whole function again.